# proof of a relationship related to half-normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, mean, standard-deviation, arithmetic

Would anyone be able to help solve this: $\dfrac{\mathbb E[|X-\mu|]}{\sqrt{\mathbb E[(X-\mu)^2]}}=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$ for a normal distribution. Related to the mean of a half-normal distribution?